# Unable to Declare Function in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I need to time a few classic ASP pages using `winmm.dll` API, but when I put this in the ASP file, I get an error:

```
<%
Declare Function timeBeginPeriod Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal uPeriod As Long) As Long
%>
```

and the error is:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation  error '800a03ea' 

Syntax error 

/Default.asp, line 2 
Declare Function timeBeginPeriod Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal uPeriod As Long) As Long
--------^
```

This error was thrown for any function declaration I tried so far, no matter what followed `Declare Function`. I also tried declaring inside `Form_Load()` with no success. `Public` or `Private` does not matter either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Declaring Window API functions is not supported like it is in VBA. The closest option is to use `Server.CreateObject()` to call a DLL exposed to COM but that can be more limited then direct Windows API access but its your best option.

Comment: I ended up just multiplying the amount of test data by 10-100 and using F12 network tab. There is only so much time to be spent on those prehistoric classic ASP apps.